# How do you iterate over a 2d array in increments and increase the increment with ruby?

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, iteration

I'm trying to grab two subarrays at a time within an array - any ideas on how to do this?

example:

```
deck = [[2,spades],[3,hearts],[6,diamonds],[10,clubs],[8,hearts],[9,clubs]]
```

Is there any way to grab two cards at a time with a loop, so the index would increase every time and go from [0..1] then [1..0] and so on to grab two cards at a time.

I'd like to put:

player 1 cards: `[2,spades],[3,hearts]`

player 2 cards: `[6,diamonds],[10,clubs]`

Comment: Note that the fact that each element of `deck` is an array is irrelevant. The same solution would apply if `deck = [:card1, :card2,..., :card6]`. Incidentally, do you mean `"spades"` or `:spaces`. As stated `spades` must be a variable or a method.

Comment: @max paspa did any of the provided answers work for you? If so, please select an answer so this shows up as a question with an answer when users search. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would just be to pass the deck array in to a method and return an array with [player1, player2, deck]. If you're just drawing from the "top" of the deck, you can just use `shift` to take the first element out of the array.

## The Long Solution

```
deck = [[2,"spades"],[3,"hearts"],[6,"diamonds"],[10,"clubs"],[8,"hearts"],[9,"clubs"]]

def drawTwo(arr)
  if arr.count >= 4
    player_one = [deck.shift, deck.shift]
    player_two = [deck.shift, deck.shift]
    return [player_one, player_two, deck]
  else
    return "Not enough cards in deck, please provide a new deck"
  end
end

round = drawTwo(deck)
player_one = round[0]
player_two = round[1]
deck = round[2]

puts "Player one: #{player_one}"
puts "Player two: #{player_two}"
puts "Deck: #{deck}"
```

I tried to be pretty detailed and not obfuscate this code much so it should read pretty explanatory.

You could make it a bit shorter by rewriting it like this, I just wanted it to be understandable what was happening:

## The Condensed Solution

```
deck = [[2,"spades"],[3,"hearts"],[6,"diamonds"],[10,"clubs"],[8,"hearts"],[9,"clubs"]]

def drawTwo(arr)
  arr.count >= 4 ? [[arr.shift, arr.shift], [arr.shift, arr.shift]] : raise "Not enough cards..."
end

player_one, player_two = drawTwo(deck)

puts "Player one: #{player_one}"
puts "Player two: #{player_two}"
puts "Deck: #{deck}"
```

Be sure to include a `deck.shuffle` when you first generate the deck.

Also, I don't know what you're using to generate the deck, but since I was having fun with it:

## Generating A Shuffled Deck

```
def newShuffledDeck
    ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
    suits = ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"]
    deck = ranks.product(suits)
    deck.shuffle
end
```

Comment: Some Ruby tips — you can write `player_one, player_two, deck = drawTwo(deck)`, Ruby does the unpacking for you. Also, no need to return the `deck` from the function, I assume you have a background in languages who do "pass by value". In Ruby everything is "pass by pointer".

Comment: @akuhn good suggestions, thanks! regarding returning deck, I assumed this would be running multiple times in some sort of game, so wouldn't they need the updated deck to continue to round 2, 3, etc without using the same cards?

Comment: The `deck` that you return points to the same object as the `deck` that you pass to the function. Hence no need to return it.

Comment: More Ruby tips — instead of returning the error message which will lend itself to followup errors, just use `raise "Not enough cards ..."` which raises a runtime exception.

Comment: You can write `deck.shift(2)` instead of `[deck.shift, deck.shift]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
hands = array.each_slice(hand_size).take(player_count)

hands.each_with_index do |hand, n|
  puts "player #{n + 1} cards are: #{hand}"
end
```

How does this work?

- `each_slice(n)` cuts the array into pieces of length `n`
- `take(n)` takes the first `n` pieces

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Enumerable::each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
deck = [[2,"spades"],[3,"hearts"],[6,"diamonds"],[10,"clubs"],[8,"hearts"],[9,"clubs"]]

deck.each_slice(2) do |el|
  puts el
end
```