# using .slice and .shift in ruby

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, slice

I'm trying to get this card game going. It should allow the user to set the number of players and distribute two cards to each player.

I sliced the deck into card pairs so

```
@deck = [["2","hearts"], ["A","spades"]],
        [["J", "clubs"], ["K","hearts"]]
```

I'm trying to distribute the next pair of cards by popping off the first pair in the deck with shift, then repeating for as my times as there users. I think it's pretty close to working - I'd appreciate any help with this.

```
    @cards=["2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King","Ace"]*4
    @suits = ["hearts", "spades", "clubs", "diamonds"]*13
    @deck = []

    puts "how many players are there?"
    number_of_players = gets.chomp.to_i


    @deck << [@cards,@suits].transpose.shuffle.each_slice(2)

      1.upto(number_of_players) do |n|
        @deck.shift
        puts "player #{n} cards are: #{@deck}"

      end
```

Comment: Best use `p` print statements to debug you program, or install the `pry` gem and use `binding.pry` to set a breakpoint so you can debug your program. The most powerful commands in `pry` are `ls` and `$`, the first print the class and all methods of an object, the later prints the source code of a method.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774523 — just use `.each_slice(2).take(number_of_players)` as I suggested there, and then loop over the result of that.

Comment: Yea, I used part of that - I'm just having trouble integrating that with my the .upto loop I have in place. With your suggestion it is taking the appropriate amount of cards, but not assigning them to the players. 

Do you know why .shift isn't working as intended? I thought it would basically iterate through the slices for me. 

Also, I'm new to stack overflow, so I didn't realize I could have just edited the original post. Thanks for the help @akuhn

Comment: `each_slice` returns an enumerator which does not support `shift` :(

Comment: I updated my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41774546/24468 — if that helps, best upvote and accept it with the checkmark

Comment: much appreciated - I'll give those a try.

Comment: Use `shift(2)` to remove 2 cards etc

Comment: What does "I think it's pretty close to working" mean? Is it working or not? If not, *how* is not working? Do you get an error? What is the error and on what line does it occur? Do you get a warning? What is the warning and on what line does it occur? Is the behavior you are observing not the one you are expecting? What is the behavior you are observing, what is the behavior you are expecting, why is that behavior the correct one? Can you specify what the exact behavior of the method should be, including all corner cases, special cases, edge cases, and exceptions? Can you provide sample …

Comment: … inputs and outputs both for "normal" cases and for all corner cases, special cases, edge cases, and exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@deck = [@cards,@suits].transpose.shuffle.each_slice(2).to_a
@initial = @deck.shift(number_of_players)

@initial.each.with_index(1) do |cards, n|
  puts "player #{n} cards are: #{cards}"
end

#⇒ player 1 cards are: [["5", "diamonds"], ["7", "spades"]]
#  player 2 cards are: [["7", "clubs"], ["10", "hearts"]]
#  player 3 cards are: [["9", "spades"], ["Queen", "spades"]]

puts "Left pairs in the deck: #{@deck.count}"
#⇒ 23 # for 3 players, it’s 26 - number_of_players
```